# How can I hide certain file types from appearing in my finder windows?

Tags: macos, finder, latex

`TeX` is great but but produces a lot of files every time I compile a document. When I open the folder containing the source `.tex` file I also see a lot of accessories file (e.g. `.log`, `.toc` that I am not really interested to.

I then would like to set Finder (not Spotlight) to visualise only files with a specific extension (e.g. `.tex`) and hide all the others every time I open and browse some folders.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to have been answered in quite some detail, albeit with respect to PDFLaTeX here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files